# Express Flash Message over multiple redirects

Tags: node.js, express

I have been using express-flash for a project and it has been working fine with redirects and page renders. However, I have a route */dashboard* which redirects further into */dashboard/admin* & */dashboard/staff* as shown in the code below. Passing a message using req.flash and redirecting to */dashboard* does not show up on the page. Other pages with single redirects are able to display the messages without any issue. I am guessing this problem is because of the second redirect from */dashboard* to */dashboard/*.*

```js
req.flash('success_msg','Successful');
res.redirect("/dashboard");

in router.js:

app.get('/dashboard', (req, res) => {
 if (req.user.role === "ADMIN") {
    res.redirect("/dashboard/admin");
  }

  if (req.user.role === "STAFF") {
    res.redirect("/dashboard/staff");
  }
})
```

**Is there a way to work around this issue, adding any statement in my router file to forward messages further into the redirects?**

Comment: Do you use `res.locals` to render flash messages?

Comment: Yes, I have made a middleware 


app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.locals.success_msg = req.flash("success_msg");
  res.locals.error_msg = req.flash("error_msg");
  res.locals.error = req.flash("error");
  next();
});

Answer (score 0):

The flash message with value `Successful` is only available inside the `req` object in the middleware that handles the `/dashboard` endpoint. If you want to further redirect, you have to assign again the flash message to the next middleware.

```
app.get('/dashboard', (req, res) => {
    // If there is any flash message with  key success_msg, 
    // give it to the next middleware
    if (res.locals.success_msg) {
        req.flash('success_msg', res.locals.success_msg)
    }

    if (req.user.role === "ADMIN") {
        res.redirect("/dashboard/admin");
    }

    if (req.user.role === "STAFF") {
        res.redirect("/dashboard/staff");
    }
})
```